# No Module named pyarrow

Tags: python, anaconda, amazon-sagemaker, pyarrow

I installed pyarrow using this command "conda install pyarrow".
I am running a sagemaker notebook and I am getting the error no module named pyarrow.
I have python 3.8.3 installed on mac.

I have numpy  1.18.5 , pandas 1.0.5 and pyarrow  0.15.1

Thanks

Comment: Does installing anything else via `conda` work? Are you possibly trying to run a different interpreter than you're installing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not yet used AWS Sagemaker notebooks, but they may be similar to GCP 'AI Platform notebooks', which I have used quite extensively. Additionally, if you're experiencing additional problems, could you describe how you're launching the notebooks (whether from command line or from GUI)?

In GCP, I defaulted to using `pip install` for my packages, as the conda environments were a bit finicky and didn't provide much support when creating notebooks sourced from my own created conda environments.

Assuming you're installing conda into your base directory, when you launch jupyter notebooks, this should be the default conda environment, else if you installed to a separate conda environment, you should be able to change this within jupyter notebooks using the `CONDA` tab and selecting which notebook uses which conda environment.
-Spencer

Comment: I am launching the sagemaker notebooks from the AWS Console

Comment: @Anu8, okay, if from the console then you may not have the option to select the conda env before launching... so check for the `CONDA` tab when your notebook is pulled up... should look something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qgkx.png